# intent.getParcelableExtra() return a null value only the first time on sending push notification

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification

I have 2 files.
One file is a messaging service called  `MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt`

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = "admin_channel"

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(p0)

        val intent = Intent(this, ChatActivity::class.java)

        val username = p0.data["title"]

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for(child in snapshot.children){
                    var user : User? = child.getValue(User::class.java)
                    if(user != null){
                        Log.d("TAG", user.username)
                        Log.d("TAG", user.image_url)
                        Log.d("TAG", user.uid)
                    }
                    intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, user)
                }
            }
            })

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationID = Random().nextInt(3000)


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupChannels(notificationManager)
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )
        /*
        val largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            resources,
            R.drawable.ic_delete
        )*/

        val notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.custom_user_icon)
            //.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle(p0?.data?.get("title"))
            .setContentText(p0?.data?.get("message"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        //Set notification color to match app color template
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.color = resources.getColor(R.color.black)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun setupChannels(notificationManager: NotificationManager?) {
        val adminChannelName = "New notification"
        val adminChannelDescription = "Device to device notification"

        val adminChannel: NotificationChannel
        adminChannel = NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        adminChannel.description = adminChannelDescription
        adminChannel.enableLights(true)
        adminChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
        adminChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel)
    }
}
```

and the second file, is an Activity called `ChatActivity.kt`

```
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

    var receiver : User? = null

    private val FCM_API = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    private val serverKey =
        "key=" + "my api key"
    private val contentType = "application/json"

    private val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this.applicationContext)
    }

    companion object{
        var date_object: Message? = null
        var sender_name :String? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

        val recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_messages)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter
        receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra<User>(NewMessageActivity.USER_KEY)
        supportActionBar?.title = receiver?.username

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid}"+"/username").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                sender_name = snapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.e("TAG", "Ricevuta stringa "+sender_name)
            }})

       }
       ....
}
```

I use an object of Parcelable class `User` as data in `putParcelableExtra()` method, this is the User class.

```
class User(val uid:String, val username:String, val image_url:String): Parcelable{
    constructor(): this("", "", "")
}
```

The problem is that the first time the notification is pressed, the `getParcelableExtra ()` method does not return the object, and therefore the `receiver` object is null. However, when a new notification is pressed again, the method returns the object that can then be used. The problem only occurs the first time you hit the notification, after the app was opened (and it wasn't already in the background).

How can I solve?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of users ? `intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, user)` , this code is inside the for loop

Comment: No, i want to get only one specific user. The for will be exectuted only one time because my query is based on username that is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you save the user with intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, user) in onDataChange callback. What happens is that the notification is shown before the code in the onDataChange callback is executed and therefore no User has been set in the intent yet.

To solve this issue you should show the notification in the onDataChange method of the MyFirebaseMessagingService class after the intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, user) call.

EDIT:

A possible solution would be:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

private val ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID = "admin_channel"

override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)

    val intent = Intent(this, ChatActivity::class.java)

    val username = p0.data["title"]

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(child in snapshot.children){
                var user : User? = child.getValue(User::class.java)
                if(user != null){
                    Log.d("TAG", user.username)
                    Log.d("TAG", user.image_url)
                    Log.d("TAG", user.uid)
                }
                intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, user)
                showNotification(intent)
            }
        }
        })
}

fun showNotification(intent: Intent){
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationID = Random().nextInt(3000)


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setupChannels(notificationManager)
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )
    /*
    val largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        resources,
        R.drawable.ic_delete
    )*/

    val notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.custom_user_icon)
        //.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setContentTitle(p0?.data?.get("title"))
        .setContentText(p0?.data?.get("message"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    //Set notification color to match app color template
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationBuilder.color = resources.getColor(R.color.black)
    }
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i found the error. I tried to pass an object on intent.putExtra() manually creating an User with constructor and the problem is solved, thank you.

Comment: I have found the problem, but i don't know where to write the puExtra() method. I have to create the object in onDataChange() method and then pass it to the putExtra() method.

Comment: Try to move the code where you create the notification (starting from creating notificationManager up to notificationManager.notify()) to a new function and call this function inside the onDataChange() method after you set the User in the extras. Just pass the intent to the new function and pass it to the pendingIntent - see the edit of my answer.

Comment: Seems to be working fine now, thanks a lot